# Open pop-under when user leave (exit)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a really great script found here : http://beeker.io/exit-intent-popup-script-tutorial

Here is the js (bioep.js) code :

```
window.bioEp = {
// Private variables
bgEl: {},
popupEl: {},
closeBtnEl: {},
shown: false,
overflowDefault: "visible",
transformDefault: "",

// Popup options
width: 400,
height: 220,
html: "",
css: "",
fonts: [],
delay: 1,
showOnDelay: false,
cookieExp: 1,


cookieManager: {
    // Create a cookie
    create: function(name, value, days) {
        var expires = "";

        if(days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }

        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    },

    // Get the value of a cookie
    get: function(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(";");

        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == " ") c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }

        return null;
    },

    // Delete a cookie
    erase: function(name) {
        this.create(name, "", -1);
    }
},

// Handle the bioep_shown cookie
// If present and true, return true
// If not present or false, create and return false
checkCookie: function() {
    // Handle cookie reset
    if(this.cookieExp <= 0) {
        this.cookieManager.erase("bioep_shown");
        return false;
    }

    // If cookie is set to true
    if(this.cookieManager.get("bioep_shown") == "true")
        return true;

    // Otherwise, create the cookie and return false
    this.cookieManager.create("bioep_shown", "true", this.cookieExp);

    return false;
},

// Add font stylesheets and CSS for the popup
addCSS: function() {
    // Add font stylesheets
    for(var i = 0; i < this.fonts.length; i++) {
        var font = document.createElement("link");
        font.href = this.fonts[i];
        font.type = "text/css";
        font.rel = "stylesheet";
        document.head.appendChild(font);
    }

    // Base CSS styles for the popup
    var css = document.createTextNode(
        "#bio_ep_bg {display: none; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #000; opacity: 0.3; z-index: 10001;}" +
        "#bio_ep {display: none; position: fixed; width: " + this.width + "px; height: " + this.height + "px; font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); background-color: #fff; box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5); z-index: 10002;}" +
        "#bio_ep_close {position: absolute; left: 100%; margin: -8px 0 0 -12px; width: 20px; height: 20px; color: #fff; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #5c5c5c; cursor: pointer;}" +
        this.css
    );

    // Create the style element
    var style = document.createElement("style");
    style.type = "text/css";
    style.appendChild(css);

    // Insert it before other existing style
    // elements so user CSS isn't overwritten
    document.head.insertBefore(style, document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0]);
},

// Add the popup to the page
addPopup: function() {
    // Add the background div
    this.bgEl = document.createElement("div");
    this.bgEl.id = "bio_ep_bg";
    document.body.appendChild(this.bgEl);

    // Add the popup
    if(document.getElementById("bio_ep"))
        this.popupEl = document.getElementById("bio_ep");
    else {
        this.popupEl = document.createElement("div");
        this.popupEl.id = "bio_ep";
        this.popupEl.innerHTML = this.html;
        document.body.appendChild(this.popupEl);
    }

    // Add the close button
    this.closeBtnEl = document.createElement("div");
    this.closeBtnEl.id = "bio_ep_close";
    this.closeBtnEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
    this.popupEl.insertBefore(this.closeBtnEl, this.popupEl.firstChild);
},

// Show the popup
showPopup: function() {
    if(this.shown) return;

    this.bgEl.style.display = "block";
    this.popupEl.style.display = "block";

    // Handle scaling
    this.scalePopup();

    // Save body overflow value and hide scrollbars
    this.overflowDefault = document.body.style.overflow;
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

    this.shown = true;
},

// Hide the popup
hidePopup: function() {
    this.bgEl.style.display = "none";
    this.popupEl.style.display = "none";

    // Set body overflow back to default to show scrollbars
    document.body.style.overflow = this.overflowDefault;
},

// Handle scaling the popup
scalePopup: function() {
    var margins = { width: 40, height: 40 };
    var popupSize = { width: bioEp.popupEl.offsetWidth, height: bioEp.popupEl.offsetHeight };
    var windowSize = { width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight };
    var newSize = { width: 0, height: 0 };
    var aspectRatio = popupSize.width / popupSize.height;

    // First go by width, if the popup is larger than the window, scale it
    if(popupSize.width > (windowSize.width - margins.width)) {
        newSize.width = windowSize.width - margins.width;
        newSize.height = newSize.width / aspectRatio;

        // If the height is still too big, scale again
        if(newSize.height > (windowSize.height - margins.height)) {
            newSize.height = windowSize.height - margins.height;
            newSize.width = newSize.height * aspectRatio;
        }
    }

    // If width is fine, check for height
    if(newSize.height === 0) {
        if(popupSize.height > (windowSize.height - margins.height)) {
            newSize.height = windowSize.height - margins.height;
            newSize.width = newSize.height * aspectRatio;
        }
    }

    // Set the scale amount
    var scaleTo = newSize.width / popupSize.width;

    // If the scale ratio is 0 or is going to enlarge (over 1) set it to 1
    if(scaleTo <= 0 || scaleTo > 1) scaleTo = 1;

    // Save current transform style
    if(this.transformDefault === "") 
        this.transformDefault = window.getComputedStyle(this.popupEl, null).getPropertyValue("transform");

    // Apply the scale transformation
    this.popupEl.style.transform = this.transformDefault + " scale(" + scaleTo + ")";
},

// Event listener initialisation for all browsers
addEvent: function (obj, event, callback) {
    if(obj.addEventListener)
        obj.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
    else if(obj.attachEvent)
        obj.attachEvent("on" + event, callback);
},

// Load event listeners for the popup
loadEvents: function() {
    // Track mouseout event on document
    this.addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;

        // Reliable, works on mouse exiting window and user switching active program
        if(!from || from.nodeName === "HTML")
            bioEp.showPopup();
    });

    // Handle the popup close button
    this.addEvent(this.closeBtnEl, "click", function() {
        bioEp.hidePopup();
    });

    // Handle window resizing
    this.addEvent(window, "resize", function() {
        bioEp.scalePopup();
    });
},

// Set user defined options for the popup
setOptions: function(opts) {
    this.width = (typeof opts.width === 'undefined') ? this.width : opts.width;
    this.height = (typeof opts.height === 'undefined') ? this.height : opts.height;
    this.html = (typeof opts.html === 'undefined') ? this.html : opts.html;
    this.css = (typeof opts.css === 'undefined') ? this.css : opts.css;
    this.fonts = (typeof opts.fonts === 'undefined') ? this.fonts : opts.fonts;
    this.delay = (typeof opts.delay === 'undefined') ? this.delay : opts.delay;
    this.showOnDelay = (typeof opts.showOnDelay === 'undefined') ? this.showOnDelay : opts.showOnDelay;
    this.cookieExp = (typeof opts.cookieExp === 'undefined') ? this.cookieExp : opts.cookieExp;
},

// Ensure the DOM has loaded
domReady: function(callback) {
    (document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete") ? callback() : this.addEvent(document, "DOMContentLoaded", callback);
},

// Initialize
init: function(opts) {
    // Handle options
    if(typeof opts !== 'undefined')
        this.setOptions(opts);

    // Add CSS here to make sure user HTML is hidden regardless of cookie
    this.addCSS();

    // Once the DOM has fully loaded
    this.domReady(function() {  
        // Handle the cookie
        if(bioEp.checkCookie()) return;

        // Add the popup
        bioEp.addPopup();

        // Load events
        setTimeout(function() { 
            bioEp.loadEvents();

            if(bioEp.showOnDelay)
                bioEp.showPopup();

        }, bioEp.delay * 1000);
    });
}
```

}

And here is the HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bioep.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
bioEp.init({
html: '<div id="#leaving-content">The content i want to print</div>',
css: '#leaving-content {padding: 5%;}'});
</script>
```

This script allow to open a pop-up when user try to leave the page. Pretty nice work. But i'm a great noob and for a personnal project i try to adapt this code to be able to run a pop-under with an another website inside an not only my own html code (like an iframe). Can you help me please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

No need for such scripts if you only want it to work for the back button, here's some simple code to do the job (requires jQuery).

```
var popupWebsite = "http://seapip.com";
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
    window.history.pushState('forward', null, './');
}
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
    $("html").append("<iframe src="+popupWebsite +" style=\"position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;\"></iframe>")
});
```

Comment: Can you explain please cause it doesn't work for me. In addition i just want a popunder when user leaves the page. Thank you